# How can I keep everything on my website on the same place when I resize the height of the website?

Tags: html, css

I have this problem i have made everything perfect responsive when your resize the width of my website but when it comes to resize height every thing gets messed up in my webpage here are some photos

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

I have tried to remove my position absolute and instead put display flex but nothing is working.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");
})

document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").forEach(n => n.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hamburger.classList.remove("active");
  navMenu.classList.remove("active");
}))
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #0B073E;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,500;0,600;1,600&display=swap');
.radient-p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(194, 146, 213, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  filter: blur(250px);
}

.radient-p-1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 50vh;
  right: 0;
  top: 386px;
  background: rgba(110, 205, 255, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  filter: blur(200px);
}


/*navbar*/

header {
  background-color: #050424;
  opacity: 1;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 100px;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

.nav-branding {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.nav-link {
  transition: 0.7s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
  body {
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
  }
  header {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  .hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  .nav-menu {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    left: -140%;
    top: 54px;
    gap: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #050424;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.3s;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .nav-item {
    margin: 16px 0;
  }
  .nav-menu.active {
    left: 0;
  }
}


/*main*/

.text-c {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 14rem;
  margin-left: 10rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.info {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.info-p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vh;
}

.salih {
  font-size: 11vh;
}

.button-cv {
  position: absolute;
  width: 17rem;
  height: 3.4rem;
  background: #6ECDFF;
  border-radius: 62px;
  border: 2px solid #6ECDFF;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  margin-top: -13rem;
  margin-left: 15rem;
  display: block;
  border-color: #6ECDFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6ECDFF;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 96vw;
  margin-left: 1.8rem;
}

.img1 {
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img1-c {
  margin-top: -7rem;
  margin-left: 65rem;
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}


/*navbar*/

@media (max-width: 1800px) {
  .img1 {
    height: 70vh;
  }
  .img1-c {
    margin-left: 65rem;
    margin-top: -2rem;
  }
  .text-c {
    margin-top: 10rem;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .button-cv {
    margin-top: -8rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1540px) {
  a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    gap: 50px;
  }
  .img1-c {
    margin-left: 55rem;
  }
  .text-c {
    margin-top: 10rem;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 6vh;
  }
  .salih {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .info-p {
    font-size: 1.4vh;
  }
  .button-cv {
    margin-top: -12rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1400px) {
  .img1 {
    height: 70vh;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1380px) {
  .img1-c {
    margin-left: 50rem;
  }
  .text-c {
    margin-top: 10rem;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 6vh;
  }
  .salih {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .info-p {
    font-size: 1.4vh;
  }
  .button-cv {
    margin-top: -12rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1308px) {
  .img1-c {
    margin-left: 45rem;
  }
  .text-c {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin-left: 6rem;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 6vh;
  }
  .salih {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .info-p {
    font-size: 1.4vh;
  }
  .button-cv {
    margin-top: -12rem;
    margin-left: 11rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1230px) {
  .img1-c {
    margin-left: 40rem;
    margin-top: -3rem;
  }
  .text-c {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin-left: 4rem;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 6vh;
  }
  .salih {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .info-p {
    font-size: 1.4vh;
  }
  .button-cv {
    margin-top: -11rem;
    margin-left: 9rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1150px) {
  .img1-c {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 17rem;
    margin-left: -4.3rem;
  }
  .text-c {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .salih {
    font-size: 8vh;
  }
  .info-p {
    font-size: 1.4vh;
  }
  .btn-c {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .button-cv {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -40rem;
    margin-right: 8.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  a {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    gap: 30px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .img1-c {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 22rem;
    margin-left: -4.3rem;
  }
  .img1 {
    max-height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .text-c {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -18rem 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .info {
    font-size: 7vh;
  }
  .salih {
    font-size: 8vh;
  }
  .info-p {
    font-size: 1.4vh;
  }
  .btn-c {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .button-cv {
    display: flex;
    width: 17rem;
    height: 3.4rem;
    background: #6ECDFF;
    border-radius: 62px;
    border: 2px solid #6ECDFF;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 550;
    display: block;
    border-color: #6ECDFF;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #6ECDFF;
    margin-top: -40rem;
    margin-right: 8.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!--==================== UNICONS ====================-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css"> -->
  <title>Responsive Portfolio Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--==================== Navbar ====================-->
  <div class="radient-p"></div>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="# " class="nav-branding">Portfolio</a>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="hamburger">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="radient-p-1"></div>
  <!--==================== main ====================-->

  <section class="text-c">
    <h1 class="info">Hello, It's Me <br> <span class="salih">Salih Morina</span></h1>
    <p class="info-p">I'm a front-end developer passionate about creating intuitive user interfaces. I specialize in HTML, CSS, JavaScript, <br> Bootstrap. </p>
  </section>

  <div class="img1-c">
    <img class="img1" src="img/My project-1 (1).png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="btn-c">
    <button class="button-cv">Download CV</button>
  </div>
  <hr>

  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
</body>
```

Comment: You specialize in Bootstrap - have you considered it for this?

Comment: Please revise your post to make it more clear what your layout should be. "Messed up" isn't a useful description. We can't propose solutions without knowing what the goal is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.